# Data source is an invalid type. It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

Tags: c#

I have a query like the following:

```
var count = db.Employees.Count (x =>(x.Salary >0));
Grid1.DataSource = count.ToString();
Grid1.DataBind();
```

It is working fine. However, why is `Grid` displaying the output column by column?

Comment: What means it's working? Your query returns an `int`. You can't use an integer as datasource for a grdiview.

Comment: where i was used int

Comment: Here: `var count = db.Employees.Count (x =>(x.Salary >0))`. Replace `var` with `int` and you'll notice that it compiles because `Count` returns an `int`. A gridview displays multiple rows with multiple columns. Maybe you want to use `Where` instead of `Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns an `int`. You can't use an integer as datasource for a gridview. The error-message is self-explanatory: the `DataSource` must be a type that implements `IListSource`, `IEnumerable` or `IDataSource`(a `GridView` usually displays multiple items).

Maybe you want to use `Where` instead of `Count`:

```
var employeeWithSalary = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Salary > 0);
Grid1.DataSource = employeeWithSalary;
Grid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: when i was execute above query im getting this error     'Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().'